# How to center img elements inside a div and move the div to the bottom of my page?

Tags: html, css, center

The thing is pretty simple. I want the `div` to be placed at bottom of the page, and then the two images to be centered.

```
<div class="social">
        <img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook"/>
        <img src="instagram.png" alt="Instagram"/>
</div>
```

I have no `CSS` because nothing worked. The only thing was to `text-align:center` the `<div>`, but this didn't make it go to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Do you want it to be stuck at the bottom whenever you scroll? Just the last thing on the page? Or the bottom of a website that is only as tall as the page?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want. But without seeing the rest of the pages html it's only a guess.

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.social {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-30-30-2.jpg" alt="Facebook" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-30-30-2.jpg" alt="Instagram" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will helps you

```
<style>
.social{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```